# Component Tree not expanding in React Developer Tools

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to inspect elements in React Apps but looking at the component tab in React Developer Tools doesn't expand the component tree for specific components as shown in the picture below. Is there a way to resolve this?

Edit: First picture shows my console and the second pic is a screenshot from Codecademy showing what the console is expected to look like with the older version of React Dev Tools.

[image: This is how my console looks]

[image: This is how the console should look with the older version of React Deve Tools]

Comment: Since you have only one component there's nothing to expand.

Comment: Just edited my post with a picture of what the expected output is supposed to be for the same app with a single component.

Comment: Sure, the second screenshot displays that there's `App-intro` component with its props inside `App`.